# Show accounts with multiple contacts to as separate columns rather than rows?

Tags: sql-server, formatting, aggregation

Suppose, I have a table of contacts.
That table has contact IDs and Account IDs 
So if I do

```
Select ContactID,AccountID From table
```

I get this:

[image]

Instead, I want to see this:

[image]

Is this plausible?

Comment: What if there are 3 contacts for an account? And what if there are 10?

Comment: Search for Pivot or (the better option) Cross Tab. And if you do need a variable number of columns, add the word "dynamic". There are 100's of examples on SO, so if you fail, post your attempt(s).

Comment: @GMB
There will only be two contacts per account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two and only two contacts par account, aggregation seems like a straight-forward option:

```
select account_id, min(contactId) contactId1, max(contactId) contactId2
from mytable
group by account_id
```

If some accounts have 2 contacts and others have just 1, then:

```
select 
    account_id, 
    min(contactId) contactId1, 
    case when count(*) > 1 then max(contactId) end contactId2
from mytable
group by account_id
```

Comment: I've never thought about doing it that way before for only two aggregations.  Nicely done.  I'd have done a left outer join with a row number or something to differentiate, but this works too.